# UPDATE COALESCE query with null values

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, coalesce

Definitely a basic question, but I couldn't find an example.

I'm writing a procedure which merges two rows into the good row. It moves all child rows' ids to being the correct one, replaces all `NULL` values with available values in the row being removed before finally deleting the 'bad' row.

What I have so far is this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`danielv`@`%` 
PROCEDURE `emp_merge`(IN `@core_emp_id` int, IN `@bad_emp_id` int)
BEGIN
    UPDATE claim SET employee_id = @core_emp_id 
    WHERE employee_id = @bad_emp_id;

    WITH bad_employee_values AS (
        SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employee_id = @bad_emp_id
    )
    UPDATE employee SET 
            employee.employment_date = COALESCE(employee.employment_date, bad_employee_values.employment_date),
    WHERE employee_id = @core_emp_id;

    DELETE FROM employee WHERE employee_id = @bad_emp_id;

END
```

However, I'm getting non-descript error messages and I'm not sure why. I suspect there's an issue with how I'm handling my CTE and coalesce function, but I'm not sure where the gap in my understanding is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement :

```
WITH bad_employee_values AS (SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employee_id = @bad_emp_id)
UPDATE employee SET 
        employee.employment_date = COALESCE(employee.employment_date, bad_employee_values.employment_date),
WHERE employee_id = @core_emp_id;
```

You are defining CTE `bad_employee_values` but you are not using it in the `UPDATE` part of the query, hence you cannot access its columns : for MySQL, `bad_employee_values.employment_date` is unknown.

It looks like you could simply avoid a CTE here. You could just self-join the table, like so :

```
UPDATE employee e_core
INNER JOIN employee e_bad ON e_bad.employee_id = @bad_emp_id
SET e_core.employment_date = e_bad.employment_date,
WHERE employee_id = @core_emp_id AND e_core.employment_date IS NULL
```

This query will simply select the record identified by `@core_emp_id`, join it with the corresponding "bad" record, and copy the value of `employment_date`. The second condition in the `WHERE` clause prevents records whose `employment_date` is not null from being selected.